# VISJS, hierarchical Layout, avoid edges crossing each other

Tags: javascript, vis.js

I display the topology of a network (not visjs network, a data network consisting of routers) using a hierarchical layout.

The layout is up/down oriented and I wonder if there is a way to influence the left/right position of nodes to avoid edges crossing each other. I have the up/down position solved via the "level" attribute. Is there a similar hint for left/right?

[image: a sample topology]

The blue edges should all be on the right, the green ones (except the one between the two top nodes) on the left (or vice versa).

Comment: I get better results when I sort the edges before updating/adding them to the network. But some cases I still have a crossing.